# console.log and .scroll listener does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create this parallax effect on a landing page. Also following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTZpNAbz3jg (skip to 21:00) for the jquery.

I am now creating the jquery side of the site, but I already have a js file for this site, and created a new one for the landing page(also tried to place the code on my main js file. But anyways, to test out the listener and console, i have this code.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    console.log('h1')

});
```

Also here is the code inside my main js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#graphics").hide();
    $("#morew").hide();

//------------landing scroll---------------//   
    $(window).scroll(function(){

    console.log('h1')

});

    //------------Toggle---------------//

  $("#hideshow1").click(function(){
    $("#photography").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#graphics").slideUp("slow");

  });

   $("#hideshow2").click(function(){
    $("#graphics").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#photography").slideUp("slow");
  });

   $("#hsw").click(function(){
    $("#morew").slideToggle("slow")
   });

   $("#hsw2").click(function(){
    $("#morew").slideUp("slow")
   });

  //------------before and after---------------//

    //------------carousel---------------//



  //------------before and after functions---------------//


  $(".top").css("width", "50%");
  $(".ba").mousemove(function(e){

    // get the mouse x (horizontal) position and offset of the div
      var offset =  $(this).offset();
      var iTopWidth = (e.pageX - offset.left);

    // set width of bottomimage div
      $(this).find(".top").width(iTopWidth);
  });

 //-----------lightbox/fancybox js---------------//

 $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows    : false,
                nextClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width  : 50,
                        height : 50
                    }
                }
            });




});
```

But apparently neither works, also here is the script link from my html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js\jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\script2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\landing.js" defer></script>      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\style2.css">
```

I also tried placing the "landing.js" script tag before the closing html tag, and tried to add "defer", but nothing works. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated, also I'm sorry I'm just starting with java/jQuery.

BASICALLY: I just wanna know why the scroll listener wont work, I created another site, just to test it out and it works fine.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Why are you linking your source files with back-slashes?

Comment: Yes, this one "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6"

Aside from that i have "GET chrome-extension://...." errors

Comment: @towerofnix thanks for that one, i updated it

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want it to do?

https://jsfiddle.net/6rp7g3kn/

uses window.onscroll without the need for jQuery:

```
window.onscroll = function(){

    $("#message").text(window.scrollY);

};
```

Comment: At the moment, I'm just trying to see if the scroll listener is working in console, so i can use it for some functions, see the youtube link, you can start at 21:10 :) 

but this one is helpful aswell thanks!